# Where can I specify an output folder for DLLs?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I am confused a bit with a new RAD Studio version! Where can I specify a folder to put my output DLL files?

Comment: Just the same as executables, build system does not distinguish between programs and libraries.

Answer (score 9):

It is under Project | Options | Delphi Compiler.

The option you are looking for is named **Output Directory** (by default `.\$(Platform)\$(config)`).

[image]

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_Compiler) says:

> Specifies where the compiler should put the executable file.

You need to be careful about the various different targets. It's easy to modify the options for the release build, go back to the IDE, compile a debug build, and then wonder why your setting has had no impact. If at all possible it is best to set the options at the highest level possible. In the screenshot above I illustrate the setting at the root level.

Answer (score 0):

in Project Options Delphi Compiler

Comment: Same place as always :-)

Comment: Unfortunatelly whatever folder I specify there the only BPL, DCU files are put to this folder, but not the DLL.

Comment: dlls go to the normal output folder. every binary goes there