# xe6 - auto deploy output to AWS S3 using REST

Tags: delphi, rest, amazon-s3, delphi-xe6

OK, new to rad studio, and enjoying it. 
We have a cross=platform product, and would like to configure XE6 to automatically deploy to compiled .exe & Dll files to specified buckets in S3.

We have looked at the cloud exploerer example which came with samples and can load the files manually using REST.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE6/en/DataSnap.Cloud_Explorer_Sample

and have checked out how to specify an output folder

[Where can I specify an output folder for DLLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410720/where-can-i-specify-an-output-folder-for-dlls)

As discussed we are not that familiar with XE6, and while they have something called a 'platform deployment manager' we don't want to setup up and EC2 instance to facilitate the process.

Does anyone have any sample scripts or advice on how to configure the output path to use the REST protocol to put the compiled files up on S3 automatically?

Comment: You should include the `delphi` tag to all your delphi related questions

Comment: In my opinion, you should be looking into using a build automation system.  I would investigate using Jenkins, along with MSBUILD, and perhaps a build-automation tool (ANT/WANT) or scripting language to accomplish such tasks. Do you really want to build from the IDE and deploy to cloud before you even pass your unit tests or do any in-house QA? If so, and that's ALL you need, investigate using a command line utility invoked as a post-build step from the IDE.

Comment: The final stage of our deployment is testing and compilation using Inno Setup, we are using Jenkins / Ec2 for this stage, but we want to source all the files from s3, rather than locally.